# cut-off line of asp.net treeview

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have an ASP.NET TreeView and need set ShowLine "true" when I define its style.
However, the treeview's lines will be cut-off.
I tried [this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/carloc/archive/2007/05/23/broken-line-in-asp-net-2-0-treeview-in-ie-7.aspx), but it didn't help.

```
.tree
{
      font-size: 40px;
      height: 40px !important;
 }

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowLines="True" CssClass="tree">
    <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="test1" Value="1">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="test1.1" Value="11"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="test2" Value="2">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="test2.1" Value="21"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

Comment: i used this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/carloc/archive/2007/05/23/broken-line-in-asp-net-2-0-treeview-in-ie-7.aspx) but it wasn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the styles mentioned in the example itself? you are missing `td div` in the style

```
.tree td div {
   height: 20px !important
}
```

[image]

That will work. Note that setting 40px is not going to work directly as it seems the vertical line image used within the div is of 20px height; hence you will need to implement your own ways if you want to change that. This would also affect the expand/collapse icon on the tree nodes.

```
.tree td div {
       height: 40px !important
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT**

The default images used are 20 x 20 pixels in size. to set your own set of images, you need to set `LineImagesFolder` property of the tree view (by doing this you will be providing your own set of images). Have a look at this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.lineimagesfolder.aspx)

Comment: when i add my style to it, cut-off lines.

Comment: @Amir I've edited my post with two screen shots (20px vs 40px). I did check on browsers FireFox 11.0, Chrome 18.0, Safari 5.1, IE 7.0/ 8.0/ 9.0. Lines does not cut off as long as the style contains 20px.

Comment: understand it work, but when set font-size treeview's property to "Larger" Cut-off occur:(